# How to embed an XML file in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am creating a simple web application for a comic using HTML and JavaScript. Because people that are not very technical should be able to add new comics, I thought about using an XML file as a configuration file.

I thought about using JSON and decided against it, mainly because the way comma's are used(no comma between two items breaks it, but a comma at the end of the list also breaks it.).

However, my question is now: How can I embed this XML file? Do I use the `<link rel= />` tag, or something else like the `<embed src= />` tag? And how can I then read information from the XML nodes in JavaScript?

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend loading a JavaScript library that makes this easy.  jQuery is one.  If you include jQuery in your page then you use it to load the document and get access to the browser's XML parsing capabilities fairly easily.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/ shows a simple example of finding values in an xml document once it's loaded.

This site http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/ gives a good example of how to load XML from a remote site.  The basic idea is to use AJAX: here's a tiny snippet for posterity that will load foo.xml after the html document has loaded (relies on jQuery):

```
$( function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
    url: "foo.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: myHandler(xml) {
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: This indeed is a correct answer. However, are there no ways to (cross browser) load an XML file in an HTML file without having to rely on post-loading strategies such as AJAX? I am trying to simply include an XML file on the same server as my HTML file.

Comment: No that's not really possible, I'm afraid, in any sensible way: you can't just embed XML *as markup* in HTML and expect different browsers to handle it in the same way.  You could try putting the XML in a TEXTAREA with style="display:none", but you would still have to parse it I think.  Interestingly: I did try embedding some random tags in a document and you can navigate them using firebug, so they must be in the DOM, but I suspect this is not reliable.

Comment: There is one last thing I'm wondering about. When using an XML file + AJAX to get it, how much slower is it than linking to a JSON file in the header?

Comment: I don't know, but the basic task is the same: fetch the file from the server, parse it, and build the tree in memory.  I've seen comparisons of XML and JSON parsing where XML wins, but YMMV

Answer (score -1):

Use [xml](http://conta.uom.gr/conta/ekpaideysh/seminaria/xml/chap3.htm) tag. Example :

```
<html>
  <xml Id = msg>
      <message>
        <to> Visitors </to>
        <from> Author </from>
        <Subject> XML Code Islands </Subject>            
      </message>
  </xml>
</html>
```

Comment: That is an XML data island. It is invalid HTML, a proprietary Microsoft feature, and Internet Explorer 10 drops support for them. Don't use these.