# Can't append XML element into DOM in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, internet-explorer-7

Is `<xml>` element a reserve thing in IE7? I can't seems to be `appendChild` this element or in this element.

DOM is showing --

```
<xml XMLDocument="[object]"></xml>
```

I need to append `<xml>` element in DOM in IE7 to able to trigger a specific function in POS system. Is there a way to escape this or do this for IE7, I can only use `.text` or `.innerText` but that won't work for my case as the function looks for XML element not a string.

expected result -- this result is from Chrome and latest IE.
[image]

using vanilla javascript:

```js
var jObj = { "Smart Shoes":{  
          "Product":"Smart Shoes",
          "Price":24.99,
          "Quantity":"1x "
       },
       "Denim Jeans":{  
          "Product":"Denim Jeans",
          "Price":30,
          "Quantity":"1x "
       }
    };

    var xml = document.createElement("xml");
        xml.setAttribute("id", "POSCMD");
        xml.setAttribute("LateProcessing", "true");
        var commands = document.createElement("commands");
        xml.appendChild(commands);
        var injFM = document.createElement("injectfieldmacro");
        injFM.setAttribute("type", "field");
        injFM.setAttribute("name", "FIELD_CLEAR");
        commands.appendChild(injFM);
        var injData;
        for (var item in jObj) {
            injData = document.createElement("injectdata");
            injData.setAttribute("type", "literal");
            injData.setAttribute("data", JSON.parse(jObj[item].Product)); // JSON.parse() older IE json2.js
            injFM = document.createElement("injectfieldmacro");
            injFM.setAttribute("type", "field");
            injFM.setAttribute("name", "FIELD_UPC");
            commands.appendChild(injData);
            commands.appendChild(injFM);
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(xml);
```

Or even jQuery

```js
var jObj = {"Smart Shoes":{"Product":"Smart Shoes","Price":24.99,"Quantity":"1x "},"Denim Jeans":{"Product":"Denim Jeans","Price":30,"Quantity":"1x "}}
    var xmlString = '<xml id="POSCMD" LateProcessing="true"><commands><injectfieldmacro type="field" name="FIELD_CLEAR"/>';

    for (var item in jObj) {
      if (jObj.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        xmlString += '<injectdata type="literal" data="' + jObj[item].Price + '"/>'; // I don't know where you got UPC from
        xmlString += '<injectfieldmacro type="field" name="FIELD_UPC"/>'
      }
    }

    xmlString += '</commands></xml>';
```

Comment: wrap the xml in this <script id="myxml" type="text/xmldata">, here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712101/embedding-xml-in-html

Comment: but that will make the xml become a text (string) in DOM not as DOM tree element.

Comment: i'm not sure you can achieve the result you want, check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546698/how-to-embed-an-xml-file-in-html